# indicating the selected menu item in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to indicate which menu item's page the user is currently in. I am developing the application using asp.net mvc2.

Is there a way to do this as for each of the menu click, i reload the entire page.

Comment: I think you need to supply an example of your menu and you code. What do you have so far? Are we talking about the template web site?

Comment: What menu are you talking about?

Comment: this is the menu that i have for the application that i generate from the sitemap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark selected item with class for ex. "active" and using css mark out this element.